# Ways to get file generated on user's PC from browser information without user input

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application on a public facing web site that requires a username and password to log into. Users log in from locations in many different countries and depending on their login location different settings are applied.

Certain users have asked for integration from this web application to another running on the same machine as they are using. They require an XML file to be saved down to a specific folder whenever a transaction occurs on the web application. They don't want the user to have to click any button or have a save dialog appear.

Obviously this is not possible using normal browser functionality for security reasons. What I want to know is this: is it possible to write some application or service that runs on those users' computers that could somehow take the transaction information from the browser and generate the file? I can modify the web application to know when it needs to do this so there can be work on both ends.

One way of doing this that I was thinking of was to have a web service running locally on all PCs where this is required, and the application will call this service when required.(e.g. a localhost url that would be setup on all required pcs )  Has anybody any other suggestions?

Comment: why use asp.net then ? simply write an application in c#. run a WCF on your server and create a downloadable client that will handle your transactions and will have access to client's machine.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not an expert on programming but I don’t think that would be possible. It would create a security risk and if it were possible then anyone could have it download a virus to your computer.